# super.method context handling in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, super

As there are no private method support yet in Javascript, I usually simply declare a normal function outside of class body and provide `this` as argument:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        _doPrivateStuff(this);
    }
}

function _doPrivateStuff(that) {
    that.bar() // private stuff
}

export default Foo;
```

But how can I acess super.method in this way?

```
function _doPrivateStuff(that) {
    super.method(); // error, 'super' outside of function or class
}
```

Besides that, is there a *good* reason why I should not be using 'private' functions like this?

Btw,  I only tried this on Babel, and using `_doPrivateStuff.bind(this)()` instead of using `that` doesn't works either

Comment: Why not do it in the constructor? Do `super.method` in the constructor

Comment: for my use case it would be too much of a detour, I actually have a higher order function that creates some functions so I can use them as methods (relying on super.method), I did managed to find an hacky workaround using arrow functions in the constructor to define methods from there and use the super inside, but it's far from elegant, and even out of curiosity, I would like to know if it's possible to handle `super` context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super` only works inside of a class itself because for `super` to work, the class needs to know `Foo`, so it can do (simplified) `Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo).prototype.method.call(this)` to call the parent class's `method`. When you just have a standalone function, there is no way for the class to know how to call `super`.

To do what you want, you'd have to do

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        _doPrivateStuff(this, () => super.bar());
    }
}

function _doPrivateStuff(that, superBar) {
    superBar();
}
```

To expand on that with a counterexample, what if your had an extra layer of classes:

```
class Base {
    method(){ console.log('base'); }
}
class Mid extends Base {
    method(){ console.log('mid'); }

    run(){ doPrivateThing(this); }
}

class Child extends Mid {}

new Child();

function doPrivateThing(that){
    // super.method();
}
```

If your example did work, you'd passed `doPrivateThing` an instance of `Child`, it has no way of knowing that it was called from inside `Mid`, should it log `mid` or `base`? There isn't enough information to know.

Comment: I am, in fact, doing exactly a workaround like that, but it's far from convenient for my use case

Comment: correction: I was doing a similar workaround using arrow functions, but actually this is different, I'll try it out

Comment: passing the arrow function as argument did work for me, thanks! Still, I'm wondering If that's a bad practice for some reason and if I should avoid doing things that require such a solution

Comment: Personally I'd avoid any call to `super` that isn't inside the child `method` directly, since it seems like an easy way to get yourself confused. I do like the approach of having helper methods outside the class, but I don't think I've had to use `super` in any of my usecases.